# How to detect parent class fields

Tags: python, django

I have a parent class and a child class which inherits parent. In a child class object, I need to differentiate between parent class fields and child class fields.

Is this information available? If so, where. Need solution in Python, specifically Django.

Comment: Is 'super()' what you want? [More info here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super)

Comment: @deinonychusaur I can only use super() to call parent class method, which I already know. Here, I _want to_ know whether a field belongs to child or parent.

Comment: Okay then the you should be able to invoke ChildClass.__mro__[1]__.field to point to PatentClass.field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider such a parent and child model:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Child(Parent):
    child_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

To make a function that determines if a field is defined in one of the parent, we should iterate over the `class.__bases__`, and try `baseclass._meta.get_field` for each

```
def is_attr_defined_on_parent(child, attr):
    for parent in child.__bases__:
        try:
            parent._meta.get_field(attr)
        except models.FieldDoesNotExist:
            continue
        else:
            return True
    return False
```

Now:

1. `is_attr_defined_on_parent(Child, 'parent_field')` returns **True**,
2. `is_attr_defined_on_parent(Child, 'child_field')` returns **False**.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, avoid any design where you need to do this. Perhaps you should be getting separate parent objects?

However, you can do this by examining the `._meta.fields` property of any django model instance.

Comment: ._meta.fields contains all fields, including parent's. How to figure where from is the field coming.

Comment: Yes, but you can examine the parent, and then take the difference of the two sets.